# Не получается изменить значение protected переменной у объекта С++

Tags: c++, ооп

Небольшое подобие игры. Есть переменная `HP` в классе `Character` (`protected` переменная) и аналогичная переменная `AP`. В `main` есть такой код:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");

string name;
HealthUp potion(integerDiffference[3]);

cout << "Укажите имя вашего персонажа." << n;
cin >> name;

Character MH(name, 100, 0 , 100);

while (MH.HPS() != 0)
{
    Character Enemy("Trob", 100, 100, 100);
    Enemy.Hit(MH);

    cout << "Что делать?" << n << "1.Атаковать" << "2.Использовать усиление"<<n;
    int Choice; 
    cin >> Choice;

    if (Choice == 1) 
    {
        MH.Hit(Enemy);
    }
    else if (Choice == 2) 
    { 
        MH.setHealth(potion); 
    }
}

cout << "Герой умирает" << n;
```

А в классе Character такой:

```
void setArmor(Armor newArmor) 
{
    newArmor.getPowerUp(&AP); 
}

void setWeapon(Weapon newWeapon) 
{ 
    newWeapon.getPowerUp(&Strong); 
}

void setHealth(HealthUp newHP) 
{
    newHP.getPowerUp(&HP); 
}

void haveDamage(int dm) 
{
    (Name == "Trob") ? (cout << "") : (cout << "Персонаж атакован!" << n);
    if (AP == 0) 
    { 
        HP = HP - dm;
    } 

    (AP < dm) ? (HP -= (dm - AP)) : (AP -= dm);
}

void Hit(Character enemy) 
{ 
    enemy.haveDamage(Strong); 
}

int HPS() 
{ 
    return HP; 
}

int *hp = &HP;

protected:
    string Name;
    int HP;
    int Strong;
    int AP;
```

Неправильность работы в том, что ни одна из `protected` переменных не изменяется на протяжении всего кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рассмотрим один из кейсов:

```
Enemy.Hit(MH);
```

Вызывается метод

```
void Character::Hit(Character enemy);
```

Данный метод принимает enemy по *значению*. Это означает что в метод будет передан не объект MH, а его *копия*. Следовательно все манипуляции произведенные с enemy внутри этого метода никак не отразятся на MH.

Что бы избежать этого следует передавать MH по ссылке или указателю:

```
void Character::Hit(Character& enemy);
```

или

```
void Character::Hit(Character* enemy);
```